# Directory exists on phone, but directory.exists() returns 'false'

Tags: java, android, file-io

In my application I want to create a folder and a subfolder for my application on the external storage.
I also check at application start whether these directories exist or not.
If not, I create them.

The problem I'm facing is that for the first folder `externalAppDirectory.exists()` returns **true**, for the **subfolder** it returns **false**.
Both folders exist at the external storage.

Here is my code:

```
private File getModuleDirectory() {
    File moduleDirectory = null;
    if (isExternalStorageReadable()) {
        File externalAppDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FallDetector");
        if (!externalAppDirectory.exists()) {
            if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                externalAppDirectory.mkdir();
                Log.d(TAG, "Created external app directory '" + externalAppDirectory.getName() + "'.");
            } else
                Log.d(TAG, "External storage not writable.");
        }
        moduleDirectory = new File(externalAppDirectory, "Modules");
        Log.d(TAG, "Is directory? " + moduleDirectory.isDirectory());
        if (!moduleDirectory.exists()) {
            if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                boolean isDirectoryMade = moduleDirectory.mkdir();
                Log.d(TAG, "Created '" + moduleDirectory.getName() + "' directory: " + isDirectoryMade + ".");
            } else
                Log.d(TAG, "External storage not writable.");
        }
    } else
        Log.d(TAG, "External storage not readable.");

    return moduleDirectory;
}
```

This is the short logcat:

```
D/ModuleLoader﹕ Is directory? false
D/ModuleLoader﹕ Created 'Modules' directory: false.
```

The `moduleDirectory` path at the return call of the method is `/storage/emulated/0/FallDetector/Modules`.

Does anyone have a clue where my problem is?

Comment: are you sure it's not supposed to be: D:/ModuleLoader ?

Comment: @Stultuske This is just the the log message. **D** is for **debug** , **ModuleLoader** is the **TAG**. You can see this in the `Log.d()` call of my code.

Comment: are you sure you have adding this permission `<user-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` before application tag?